# Semialgebraic set with distance

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $f(x)$be a polynomial with variables in $\mathbb{R}^n$

We note $$g(x)=\sum_{3\le |\alpha|\le r} |\partial_x^{\alpha}f(x)|^{\frac{1}{|\alpha|}}$$
 $$E=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n, \;|\nabla f(x)|^{\frac{4}{3}}\ge 2\Big(|Hess f(x)|+(g(x))^4\Big)\right\}$$
and
$$F=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n, dist(x,\mathbb{R}^n \backslash E)\le \frac{2}{g(x)}\right\}$$

> I want to prove that $F$ is a semialgebraic set.

Please help me to do so. Thanks

Comment: Two questions: What is the meaning of $\alpha$ - is it an index, a multi-index, an integer, etc? How much do you know about semialgebraic sets/functions? (If you know that the image or preimage of a semialgebraic set under a semialgebraic map is again semalgebraic and that compositions of semialgebraic functions are semialgebraic, a lot of this problem should become very easy.)

Comment: $\alpha$ is a multi-index in $\mathbb{N}^n$ i don' know a lot about semialgebraic sets/functions but i know that  compositions of semialgebraic functions are semialgebraic. I don't manage to answer my problem, if you have the right way, please help me to do so, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For any rational number $r \in\Bbb Q$, the function $x\mapsto |x|^r$ is semialgebraic. As $\partial^{\alpha} f(x)$ is again a polynomial, this shows that $g$ is semialgebraic.

Since magnitude of a vector with semialgebraic entries is again semialgebraic, $|\nabla f(x)|^{\frac43}$ is a semialgebraic function, and since $|Hess f(x)|$ is the absolute value of a polynomial, this shows that both sides of the equation in $E$ are semialgebraic, and so the set of things satisfying this inequality is again semialgebraic.

Since the distance function to a semialgebraic set is semialgebraic (and semialgebraic sets are closed under complements), $F$ is semialgebraic.

All of the statements above are very basic - I would recommend reviewing an overview article (like http://www.journalofsing.org/volume13/article4.html) or beginning book if they're not sticking.